# Upload files to Google Drive using Dropzone

Tags: ajax, google-api, dropzone.js

This is my current code used for the uploading task:

```
$imagesDropzone.dropzone
  init: ->
    this.on 'sending', (file, xhr) ->
      xhr.setRequestHeader 'Content-Type', file.type

  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media'
  method: 'post'
  maxFileSize: 5
  paramName: 'images-dropzone-input'
  headers:
    'Authorization': "Bearer #{ uploadBundle.accessToken }"
  addRemoveLinks: 'dictRemoveFile'
```

And it doesn't work (all uploaded files are broken).
I know I need to do something like this:

```
xhr.send file
```

But I don't know where to put this call. How can I override the `send` behavior of Dropzone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After take a look on the source code of Dropzone, I figure out a way to do it by overriding the instance method `uploadFiles`:

```
imagesDropzoneInstance = new Dropzone '#imagesDropzone',
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media'
  method: 'post'
  maxFileSize: 5
  paramName: 'images-dropzone-input'
  headers:
    'Authorization': "Bearer #{ uploadBundle.accessToken }"
  addRemoveLinks: 'dictRemoveFile'

imagesDropzoneInstance.uploadFiles = (files) ->
  uploadFiles: (files) ->

    .. copy the uploadFiles method of Dropzone, modify, then paste here..

    # Add the end:
    xhr.send files[0] # This overrides the default upload behavior.
```